# Ubuntu 16.04 Build OpenLDAP from source

Tags: software-installation, compiling, patch, openldap

I want to enable slapd feature --enable-spasswd. So I download OpenLDAP source code from this url.

http://mirror.eu.oneandone.net/software/openldap/openldap-release/openldap-2.4.44.tgz

Then I run configure with the following parameters.

```
./configure \
    --prefix=/usr \
    --libexecdir=/usr/sbin \
    --sysconfdir=/etc/ldap/ \
    --localstatedir=/var/run \
    --datarootdir=/usr/share \
    --datadir=/usr/share/slapd \
    --disable-ypt \
    --enable-modules \
    --enable-rlookups \
    --enable-overlays \
    --with-tls \
    --disable-sql \
    --with-system-libtool \
    --disable-ltdl-install \
    --enable-spasswd \
    --with-cyrus-sasl \
```

Once the build completed and then start the OpenLDAP process by this command. But the process exit immediately. After that, I tried to diagnostic the problem by strace.

```
unlink("/var/run/run/ldapi")            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
umask(0)                                = 022
bind(8, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/run/ldapi"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

My question is, how is the slapd package being configured in Ubuntu 16.04. Is it possible to read the Makefile that is used to build the apt package?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found out that I can get the source `apt-get source` and `debuild`. And by that, I learned the `slapd` in debian package has all the options enabled.